# How does nload determine the total traffic?

Tags: linux

The tool `nload` shows the current, average, minimum, maximum and ttl incoming and outcoming traffic for (a specific) network interface.

My questions:

- How does nload determine the total data traffic?
- How is the current traffic determined?
- Is the ttl data simply the up added current traffic or is there a file on a Linux machine which keeps track of this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the source code, the file `devreader.cpp` references:

- sys/socket.h
- time.h
- net/if.h
- netinet/in.h
- arpa/inet.h

It reads in from /sys/class/net and /proc/net/dev. If you want to find out how this works, you will have to find out how the kernel implements this,

Comment: Thanks
I looked into those folders and found at /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes and tx_bytes the according values for the ttl data sent/received.

Comment: @Moka If this was helpful and answered your question, could you mark it as the answer?